# Read Only Transaction or No Lock Query (Go)

Tags: sql, sql-server, go, optimization

I am currently working on fixing some performance issues we are having with our application. I am curious to hear what/if are the best practices for my situation. I have a SELECT statement that is causing locks to happen. Would it be more advisable to just have the select query have (nolock) or setup a read-only transaction? From what I've found, setting up a transaction is the only way to set RO in Go.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [pipe].[Message]
ORDER BY [MessageID] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the above T-SQL is causing locks that is blocking *other* transactions? `NOLOCK` doesn't stop the taking of locks; it means that it takes dirty reads on the table, and can result in missing or duplicate (different) rows. If the above query *is* causing locks, then `NOLOCK` won't chaneg that; it sounds more like the query is being run with some kind of other hint.

Comment: My DBA told me that the above query blocks itself repeatedly. I added the table he sent me showing this. How does putting nolock on a query that is locking not stop it from locking?

Comment: That means nothing on its own. How long are these queries waiting to get a share lock? A `SELECT` using share lock isn't a problem.

Comment: The select query is very likely to get blocked by any concurrent inserts as it is reading the rows with the highest id. Have you considered read committed snapshot isolation?

Comment: Create an index on MessageID.